# Sql select query with count

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have a fb_requests table. [image]

I would like to select game_selected column based on accept_status, if accept_status count < 4 , i want to select those rows. tried hard to get it working, please help me to solve this issue.

This is my create table code

```
CREATE TABLE `fb_requests` (                                              
               `id` int(60) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                                   
               `user_id` int(60) DEFAULT NULL,                                         
               `fb_user_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,                                 
               `request_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,                                 
               `game_selected` int(60) DEFAULT NULL,                                   
               `accept_status` int(60) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0 = pending 1 = accept',  
               `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,                                   
               `modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,                                  
               PRIMARY KEY (`id`)                                                      
             ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=190 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Tried this code. i know its not syntactically correct but tried it.

```
Select 
    game_selected 
from 
    fb_requests
where 
    user_id = 17 
    && 
    (
        count(accept_status =1) < 4
    ) 
group by 
    game_selected;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what would you like to see? Please describe what you want to achive.

Comment: As a general rule, `CREATE TABLE` code (posted as text, with irrelevant columns omitted) and a few `INSERT INTO` queries with sample data are more useful than a picture of your data because it allows potential answerers to actually test the query.

Comment: I would like to select game_selected column based on accept_status, if accept_status count < 4 -- You want the accept_status count or the count of rows where accept_status =1 ?

Comment: @Dibish: can you place your table and data on SQL Fiddle? It would be easier to fetch the correct result on your available data. Or please provide your sample data in the form of insert query here which I can import.

Comment: @Dibish: Can you try the answer I have posted and give your feedback. It should work with every value of accept_status.

Answer (score 1):

You should use HAVING sql statement with aggregate functions
Try this

```
Select game_selected from fb_requests
where user_id=17 
group by game_selected
having count(accept_status)<4;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, its working, is there any way to take count(accept_status=1) only

Comment: @Dibish yes you can modify the WHERE statement to be like this  where user_id=17 AND accept_status=1

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    Select game_selected from fb_requests
    where user_id=17 
    group by game_selected
    having count(accept_status)<4;
```

**Update:**

```
    Select game_selected from fb_requests
    where user_id=17 and accept_status=1
    group by game_selected
    having count(accept_status)<4;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply, how can i select accept_status=1 records with the same query? I mean i want to take the count of accept_status=1 only

Answer (score 1):

I think its because of the aggregate function, try this.

```
Select game_selected 
from fb_requests
where user_id=17
group by game_selected
HAVING COUNT(accept_status) < 4;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply, how can i select accept_status=1 records with the same query? I mean i want to take the count of accept_status=1 only

Answer (score 1):

Please try following queries as per your requirements

```
Select game_selected,count(accept_status) as as_cnt
    from 
        fb_requests
    where 
        user_id = 17 
    group by 
        game_selected
 having as_cnt < 4;
```

**OR**

> following query for only accept_status marked as '1'

```
    Select 
        game_selected,sum(accept_status) as as_cnt
    from 
        fb_requests
   where 
            user_id = 17 
        group by 
            game_selected
     having as_cnt < 4;
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Where clauses can only use existing columns or combinations (but not aggregations) of existing columns. OK I see you edited this and used having instead.

Comment: @YograjSudewad SudewadThank you so much for your code, in your second query am not getting accept_status = 1 count

Comment: the second query counts only those records whose accept_status = 1 (for ex. you have 5 records from that 3 have accept_status = 1 and 2 have accept_status = 0 then that time its return sum as 3 because its count only accept_status = 1 records)

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
Select fbr1.game_selected,fbr1.* from fb_requests fbr1 JOIN 
(select id,accept_status from fb_requests where accept_status =1 limit 4) fbr2
 ON fbr1.id=fbr2.id where fbr1.user_id = 17;
```

Let me know if you are not looking for the result fetched from above query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not tried it. I will try it and let u know. Below answer worked for me that's why i didnt tried this answer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Select game_selected from fb_requests where user_id=17 group by game_selected having count(accept_status)<4;

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply, how can i select accept_status=1 records with the same query? I mean i want to take the count of accept_status=1 only